# Java - write the first byte of an int

Tags: java, int, byte

Ok, so I have searched and searched and nothing worked...
I have this array of int, each int occupies only the low order byte. For instance, I have

```
data[0] = Ox52
data[1] = Oxe4
data[2] = Ox18
data[3] = Oxcb
```

I want that the standard output contains exactly those bytes (or in other words, if I write this in a file and I examine the file with a Hex editor, I should see):

52e418cb

How can I do that?

Thank you for your help

Comment: why don't you use a `byte` array?

Comment: Because I am trying to adapt an AES implementation for my personal use and it is using int arrays. And I still can not make it work, I have an array of 16 int (therefore, I should get 16 bytes) and I get 24 bytes in the end >.<

Comment: so your actual question is how to write binary data to stdout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to work fine.  I'm using the `OutputStream.write(int)` method.

```
int[] ints = new int[] { 0x52, 0xe4, 0x18, 0xcb };
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("/tmp/x"));
for (int i : ints) {
    os.write(i);
}
os.close();
```

Results:

```
> hexdump /tmp/x
0000000 52 e4 18 cb
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of doing this is to shift the bytes according to their desired position and then stitch them together using the OR operator. But, you should also perform a bit mask on the lower 8 bits of the byte before shifting it. This is needed because a byte is first converted to an int (before the shifting is done). This is no big deal, but when the highest bit is 1 (i.e.: the byte is negative), your integer will become negative as well, which causes all the leading bits to be set on 1.

So:

```
(byte) 10000000 = (int) 11111111 11111111 11111111 10000000
```

Using this negative int value with the OR operator will cause a wrong result. So, the working line is this one:

```
((data[0] & 0xFF) << 24) | ((data[1] & 0xFF) << 16) | ((data[2] & 0xFF) << 8) | (data[3] & 0xFF)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just shift and OR them together before writing them to the file/output:

```
(data[0] << 24) | (data[1] << 16) | (data[2] << 8) | data[3]
```

Comment: @Sid A Java `int` is always 32 bits, no matter what architecture you're on. In any case, the concept is easily extended to 64 bits.

Comment: Yeah but in case they write a VM with a 64 bit int at some point. I guess that's unlikely but still might be worth to use a size operator or something to figure how much to shift.

Comment: @moooeeeep: If there's other garbage in the `int`, there's a bigger problem :) But if that's what's actually necessary, then sure. Adding that now would make it a little unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @Sid: Nope.  There's already 64-bit Java JVMs, but the JSR specifies that an int is _always_ 32 bits, no matter what.

Comment: @LouisWasserman point taken. BTW I like this way of doing it better than the OutputStream in the accepted answer above so +1 for that.